# IPython - Is it possible to use the Tornado ioloop?

Tags: python, asynchronous, ipython, tornado

I'm working on some code that requires a background task to be running asynchronously in IPython. For running tasks in the background, I figured I could use the same Tornado ioloop that IPython uses. Is there a way to get a handle on the current ioloop instance, and add callback to it?

In the simplest sense, I want to run a function like `f()` below in the background:

```
from tornado import ioloop
import datetime

def f():
    print "Hi!"

i= ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
dt = datetime.timedelta(seconds=4)

ioloop.PeriodicCallback(f, 2000).start()

i.start()
```

Yet, when I load this file `tornado_test.py` from IPython, I can't simultaneously type commands while this is being printed:

```
In [1]: import tornado_test
Hi!
Hi!
```

Can I use the IPython ioloop for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with doing this is that the `i.start()` call blocks. Tornado is a single-threaded framework; you only get asynchronous behavior by actually running code *inside* the event loop. So while the event loop is running in the main thread, the only code that can run is what's scheduled inside the loop.

However, you could get the behavior you want by running the `i.start()` command in a background thread, like this:

```
from tornado import ioloop
import datetime

def f():
    print "Hi!"

i= ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
dt = datetime.timedelta(seconds=4)

ioloop.PeriodicCallback(f, 2000).start()
t = threading.Thread(target=i.start)
t.start()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, dano. But it somehow feels like running `i.start()` on a thread is kind of an "unnatural" for what I want. Like you said, I want this function to be running inside the single-threaded Tornado ioloop. I probably shouldn't even be starting it, since it's already started. I just want to add callbacks to it. Also, the user interacting with the system may dynamically add many other functions, and running a permanent background thread for each of them seems like an overhead?

Comment: @user1496984 Are you talking about IPython notebook specifically? Otherwise, I don't think there is a tornado ioloop running in IPython. If there were, you wouldn't be able to call `i.start()` in your example code - it would raise an exception.

Comment: Ah, great catch. The code does work when used in the IPython notebook. The console version if IPython does not use the Tornado IOLoop (unless it's launched as `ipython console`). Thanks!